# Mapping two classes in a query in Automper Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have two classes, one of which is an entity and the other is a view model, I want to map with automapper them to each other inside the desired service when querying so that I can use the lazy loading feature that IQueryable provides, but I don't know how to do it.

Mapping Profile :

```
CreateMap<User, EditProfileViewModel>();
```

If I don't use automapper, my code will look something like below :

```
public Task<EditProfileViewModel> GetUserForEditProfileAsync(int userId)
=> _users.Select(u => new EditProfileViewModel()
{
    Id = u.Id,
    DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
    Email = u.Email,
    UserName = u.UserName
}).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
```

`_users : DbSet<User>`

How do I implement this using autoMapper?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Should I use the projectTo instead of the map?

Comment: Yes, `ProjectTo` fits best here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu 
Thanks, I was able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make changes accordingly.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IMapper mapper;
    public AccountController(IMapper mapper) 
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }


    public Task<EditProfileViewModel> GetUserForEditProfileAsync(int userId)
    {
          var user = await _users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
          return mapper.map<EditProfileViewModel>(user)
    }
}
```

You must need to having same signature of propertiese, otherwise you have to configure each property as per required.

Comment: I came up with this code with the help of a friend in the comments, isn't it more optimal to use projectTo?
`=> _mapper.ProjectTo<EditProfileViewModel>(_users).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);`

Comment: I dont think to have "ProjectTo" extension in mapper.map.  and Your above mentioned code will getting all list _users and then you apply filter. And In my code first _users apply filter by id and then converting to Automapper object.

Comment: But the projectTo returns you an IQueryable, so it acts as a lazy load and does not execute a query until the singleOrdefault.